# HTML 5 are the new tags header/nav/aside/section etc containers like div?

Tags: html, tags

As the title says, do I have to use these new tags in a DIV or  are they basically DIVs themselves?

Comment: No, they can stand on their own.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how each of the major HTML5 tags can/should be used:

> section – Used for grouping together thematically-related content. Sounds like a div element, but it’s not. The div has no semantic meaning. Before replacing all your div’s with section elements, always ask yourself: “Is all of the content related?”
>
> aside – Used for tangentially related content. Just because some content appears to the left or right of the main content isn’t enough reason to use the aside element. Ask yourself if the content within the aside can be removed without reducing the meaning of the main content. Pullquotes are an example of tangentially related content.
>
> header – There is a crucial difference between the header element and the general accepted usage of header (or masthead). There’s usually only one header or ‘masthead’ in a page. In HTML5 you can have as many as you want. The spec defines it as “a group of introductory or navigational aids”. You can use a header in any section on your site. In fact, you probably should use a header within most of your sections. The spec describes the section element as “a thematic grouping of content, typically with a heading.”
>
> nav – Intended for major navigation information. A group of links grouped together isn’t enough reason to use the nav element. Site-wide navigation, on the other hand belongs in a nav element.
>
> footer – Sounds like its a description of the position, but its not. Footer elements contain informations about its containing element: who wrote it, copyright, links to related content, etc. Whereas we usually have one footer for an entire document, HTML5 allows us to also have footer within sections.

Answer (score 0):

**`<header>`**

The `<header>` element represents a container for introductory content or a set of navigational links.

A  element typically contains:

one or more heading elements ( - ) logo or icon authorship information You can have several  elements in one document.

Note: A `<header>` tag cannot be placed within a ,  or another  element.

---

**`<nav>`**

The `<nav>` tag defines a set of navigation links.

Notice that NOT all links of a document should be inside a `<nav>` element. The `<nav>` element is intended only for major block of navigation links.

---

**`<aside>`**

The `<aside>` tag defines some content aside from the content it is placed in.
The aside content should be related to the surrounding content.

---

**`<section>`**

The `<section>` tag defines sections in a document, such as chapters, headers, footers, or any other sections of the document.

---